# QGIS fixed length measurement

Tags: qgis, distance

im trying to place points at a fixed distance from each other, is there a way to place two points at a fixed distance from each other?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

**One way** would be to use the CadTools plugin. There you have a Rectangular Point creator.

[image]

The Select Line Segment button (left one) lets you select a line segment of an existing line in a line layer. This line is used as a local coordinate system as the x-axes. You enter how many map units you go in x- and then y-direction for the new point.

[image]

**Another way** is through the Advanced Digitizing panel. In construction mode you can fix the distance for creation of new point in relation to a clicked point in map.

[image]

The advanced Digitizing Panel is available when the Advanced digitizing toolbar is on, you layer is editable and the add feature button is activated like below.

[image]